# Android built-in browser and download

Tags: android, http, apk, android-browser

This is driving me nuts. I want to offer an `.apk` file for download. All browsers I've tested will download my file without any problem. Except for the built-in browser in android. For some strange reason it will repeat the request for the resource. Using BurpSuite I've discovered that the apk file is transferred flawlessly. I proxy the file, but I send the headers right away, using curl I could confirm the headers are sent and the content starts being transmitted in the following. I've compared my headers with the headers sent by `threema.ch` which works flawlessly.

These headers are sent by my application:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 16 Aug 2014 16:41:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.apk"
Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive
Transfer-Encoding: Chunked
```

These headers are sent by Threema:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 16 Aug 2014 17:49:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive
Content-Length: 14146751
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Threema-1.63.apk"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
```

I've first loaded the file through an iframe. Currently I'm redirecting the browser to the download using HTTP redirect. I offer the file from a different subdomain. But I also tried delivering the file from the same domain and using a html link.

These are the headers sent by the client. First:

```
GET /download/download/NlnMhaeXmcjSosfqRTcG8YdxQgQGSxTWQeE10-GrH4U HTTP/1.1
Host: l.dl.test
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 7 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://l.google/device/deviceid/351cd7c24f637eb5?token=6Xf3nJIIMIa4toKrpTqgDGFjAKzeBBoaeduMmcIMeGY
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,en-US;q=0.8
X-Requested-With: com.android.browser
```

And then (around 20s later):

```
GET /download/download/NlnMhaeXmcjSosfqRTcG8YdxQgQGSxTWQeE10-GrH4U HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 7 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Referer: 
cookie: 
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: l.dl.test
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I'm generating a download id for one time use. The second Request will fail, because the id becomes invalid after the first request. The download works if I permit the second attempt to download the file.

Might it be that the android browser wants compressed content in the first attempt and if it gets identity content it will make a second attempt using Accept-Encoding identity? I also tried setting `Content-Encoding: identity` without luck.

**Workaround:**
The only way I've got this working without sending the .apk twice is using this very stupid (and properly error-prone) workaround:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.apk\"");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');

// Ugly workaround for bug in built-in android browser.
if (
  isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
  && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'com.android.browser')
  && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])
  && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'identity') === FALSE)
) {
    // The built-in android browser will make two requests for the apk
    // file, one with Accept-Encoding gzip and deflate and one with
    // Accept-Encoding identity. But it will only serve the second request
    // with Accept encoding identity. So stop the first request.

    // If the first request is shown, the workaround didn't work.
    die ("Oh no! I'm sorry. The built-in android browser has a nasty bug."
    . " It's hard to work around. If you see this the workaround failed."
    . " Please try downloading with a different browser.");
}
```

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment` has long been an issue with Android.

Comment: Removing `Content-Disposition: attachment` did not helped. But thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean for you to remove it. I meant for you to search the Internet for help with that header, or to switch to another file download approach.

Comment: By the way if I set Content-Disposition: inline it works, but it opens (as requested) in the browser. Same if I drop Content-Disposition and Content-Type. I tried a lot of different Content-Disposition and Content-Type combinations and in all either the browser displayed the file or it sends two requests.